# How to extract or filter for a date in google earth engine data

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to go back in time and visualise the hydrology of the past. I am using the MERIT Hydro data set in google earth engine which states a time range of multiple years.

- How can I filter for the earliest data set available?
- Is the data downloaded aggregated information?

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MERIT_Hydro_v1_0_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dataset is an ee.Image not an ee.ImageCollection.

The date range does not specify individual images in a collection but the date range of the original datasets that were used to compile the MERIT Hydro: global hydrography dataset, as one image. Individual images with specific dates cannot be accessed in this dataset.

Read more: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2019WR024873